# Custom 404 not firing from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to handle 404 errors when using a [cms](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa) gem.  In my past application this 404 method seemed to work but now its not rescuing the error.  Any ideas?

```
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_404

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    admin_cms_path
  end

private

  def render_404(exception = nil)
    if exception
      logger.info "Rendering 404: #{exception.message}"
    end
    flash[:error] = 'The page you entered is unavailble, please send us an email if this is unexpected'
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

and the routes

```
# routes.rb
Amskier::Application.routes.draw do
  # ...    
  comfy_route :blog_admin,        path: '/admin'
  comfy_route :cms_admin,         path: '/admin'

  root to: "cms/content#show"

  comfy_route :cms,               path: '/', sitemap: false
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the route to this action of controller:

```
match 'path' to: 'errors#catch_404'
```

and create errors controller like this

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def catch_404
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new(params[:path])
  end
end
```

after this it should start working.

Comment: In Rails 3.x.x, ApplicationController can't catch ActionController::RoutingError and thus, we cannot take advantage of rescue_from like we used to for ActiveRecordError::RecordNotFound. You can go ahead with @Babar's solution. Put your route at the end of all routes.